# Symfony2 user password change

Tags: php, symfony

Good morning, i'm trying to do a password change form but without any success so far i've been doing research on this part and i didn't find any useful results on google so i came here :D

This is my controller action for password  change

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/user/change-password", name="change_password")
 * @Template()
 *
 */
public function changePasswordAction(Request $request) {
    $changePasswordModel = new ChangePassword();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), $changePasswordModel);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
        $changePassword = $form->getData();

        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($changePassword->getUser());

        var_dump($encoder);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($changePassword->getUser()->getPlainPassword(), $changePassword->getUser()->getSalt());

        $changePassword->getUser()->setPassword($password);

        $em->persist($changePassword->getUser());
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('change_password_success'));
    }

    return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
}
```

Password Change Model

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
 *     message = "Wrong value for your current password"
 * )
 */
 protected $password;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min = 6,
 *     minMessage = "Password should by at least 6 chars long"
 * )
 */
 protected $plainPassword;

public function setUser(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setPassword($password) {

    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword() {

    return $this->password;
}

public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword) {

    $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;

    return $this;
}

public function getPlainPassword() {

    return $this->plainPassword;
}
```

Password Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('password', 'password');
    $builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        'required' => true,
        'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
    ));
    $builder->add('ChangePassword', 'submit');
}
```

My current error is :

```
No encoder has been configured for account "".
500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException
```

Forgot to add the security.yml

```
    encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 15
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: Where do you set the user for `$changePasswordModel`?

Comment: in the controller $changePasswordModel = new ChangePassword();

Comment: From your code, you don't set the user to this model. You only use the getter, never the setter.

Comment: in the controller getfattory you need to pass the class not the object. So try this:         `$encoder = $factory->getEncoder(get_class($changePassword->getUser() ));`

Comment: that line is for fosuserbundle no ? i copied from there only get_class() part and i get No encoder has been configured for account "AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController".  btw i'm doing the user system from scratch to learn more about symfony

Comment: check the security.yml under the encoders listed by class name

Comment: I'll have to ask again, where do you set the user object to `$changePasswordModel`. Currently I'd bet `var_dump($changePassword->getUser());` would be `NULL`. Another hint is that `get_class($changePassword->getUser())` gives `SecurityController` which will only be the case when the supplied argument is null, because `get_class` then defaults to the class it's called in.

Comment: try in the controller to take the encoder in this manner: `$encoder = $factory->getEncoder('AppBundle\Entity\User');`

Comment: indeed it is null, and the user object i set it in Password Change Model which is posted there is a var there user with an assert on it.

Comment: If it's null, then no user object is set. An assert on the entity will not magically inject the entity. And with no user object, the encoder does not know what to do. Try `$changePasswordModel->setUser($this->getUser());`

Comment: that code will work for sure.. but the question that comes in my mind i did the change password template like registration from sf article ... a type a model everything the same.. why didn't inject.. like it does on register action .. hmmh

Comment: Can't say without seeing the article you mention. Nonetheless, this question here is really just a matter of not wiring everything up correctly.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html this article :D

Comment: Ok, the register works, because the user object is newly created and the class is correct because the form type uses `'data_class' => 'Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User'`. Your `ChangePassword` class on the other hand is actually just a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). There is no implicit magic that would fetch and set the correct user entity in this context.

Comment: ok now i got it :D ... i didn't understand why it worked on register and here it didn't .. :D now i know why :D and according to your answer how should i change / improve the code ?

Comment: and can you post an answer to the question so i can validate as correct one ? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code you never set the actual user for which you want to change the password. Because of this, the following line fails, as `null` is passed as the argument:

```
 $factory->getEncoder($changePassword->getUser());
```

If you want to stick to your current implemenation, you only need to realize that `ChangePassword` is actually just a [data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) which needs to be set up correctly.
Parts of this setup will come through the form handling (`ChangePasswordType`) other parts have to be set explicitly by you. So, for example just add:

```
$changePasswordModel = new ChangePassword();
$changePasswordModel->setUser($this->getUser());
```

Personally I think this aproach is a good idea because it makes the code more semantic (or expressive if you will). Just remember to not assume to much about implicit *magic* on the side of symfony.

Comment: About the magic of symfony.. well .. i kinda got used with it's magic and i expect to do everything :))

Comment: Trust me, I know what you're saying! ;)